# Web service returns different value each time I request

Tags: c#, web-services

I got a web service running on c# but recently, something strange happened. Even when I query from a simple table with only 1 value like this:

```
string str = "";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Main.ConnectionStringTD"]))
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            Connection = connection,
            CommandText = "select Version from TN_Version"
        };
        str = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        str = "ERROR:" + exception.Message + "_" + exception.InnerException.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message ?? "");
    }
    return str;
}
```

This always returns correct value when I debug on local but an error message returned whenever I publish this service on host and execute it:

> There is no row at position 0.

It's really strange cuz this is a simple table and absolute nothing changes or delete its value...

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Lqm.png)

And I have to execute the service 3 or 4 times until it gets me the correct value:

```
<string xmlns="http://webservice.com/">6.7</string>
```

Please, someone helps me, this have been bugging me to no end. Thanks you so much (really)

Comment: Did you try to close the connection?

Comment: Sir, as far as I know: there's no need to Close or Dispose the using block will take care of that for you... This is from MSDN: "The following example creates a SqlConnection, opens it, displays some of its properties. The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block."

Comment: Yes, I know but it worth a try.

Comment: What type of database (full sql, sql express, localdb). How does the source table get populated?

Comment: @TamásKecskeméti: I tried it, no luck :((

Comment: @BrendanGreen: It's SQL Enterprise Edition, sir.

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means that no rows were returned by your query. so maybe, after you hosted the app, either IIS or a firewall causing this problem in the connection.  Check with the firewall turned off and check the rights of your IIS user account.

Comment: Ok, but julanove says: "I have to execute the service 3 or 4 times until it gets me the correct value"

Comment: Yes, that's bit strange, though. Maybe the connection gets succeed only after a few attempts.